# Creating field from number of items separated by "|" in field in QGIS

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, fields-attributes, count, self-intersection

I am trying to create an index field from an intersection layer I have created using the SAGA's "Polygon Self-Intersection" tool.

The SAGA tool outputs a field that shows which buffers intersect each other separated by a `"|"`. I would like just a simple count of the number of intersections - so I need a way to count the number of numbers between the `"|"` in that field.

Comment: Is this about the SAGA tool in the QGIS Processing Toolbox? (judging from the way of capitalization  - it will be written like `Polygon Self-Intersection` in native SAGA gui).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IF you are working on QGIS Field Calculator, try:

```
length("ID") - length(replace("ID", '|', '')) + 1
```

- SAGA polygon self-intersection tool will store the ids in a new field `"ID"` which can be used in this expression to designate the field.
- `replace("ID", '|', '')` will remove `|` character from the `"ID"`field, so `length(replace("ID", '|', ''))` is the length of the numbers included in the `"ID"`.
- Then subtracting the length of the above from the original length, is the number of the `|`.
- By adding `1` to the number of `|`, you will obtain the count of numbers between the `|`.

I honestly have no answer/idea if the question is about the SAGA GUI.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative you may try the following expression:

```
array_length(string_to_array("ID", delimiter:='|'))
```

[image: result]